# VSCode terminal change from python 3.7 to 3.6

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, dlib

I want to install dlib but since it only [supports](https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/) python 3.6, I have to downgrade my python 3.7.

I was able to create an environment and already selected it on my VSCode but whenever I check my terminal for the python version, it's still stuck on 3.7.

Can someone help me on this?

[image: See image]

Comment: I am not a windows user and I haven't done a lot of python coding lately (so I can't give you a definitive answer), but you should look into virtual environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `python` in the terminal, the version used is resolved by the `PATH` variable. You may want to specify the full path to the Python version you want (in Windows, use `where python` to list all possibilities), or modify the `PATH` variable and change the order. Depending on the installation method, the full path to `python` may look like `C:\Python36\python.exe`

Comment: Can you tell me which `PATH` is this? On the settings.json, I already directed it on 3.6 version. `{
  "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\ELITEBOOK\\anaconda3\\envs\\py36\\python.exe"
}
`

Comment: You don't need to modify your `PATH`, you can run Python 3.6 directly. What does `where python` output?

Comment: Also, the vscode setting `python.pythonPath` is distinct from the `PATH` system variable.

Comment: It doesn't return anything

Comment: here the output when I used terminal from anaconda `C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`

Comment: OK, so now rather than writing `python` at your terminal to run Python, write `C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\anaconda3\python.exe`.

Comment: still version 3.7

Comment: So in vscode when you press CTRL+SHIFT+P and write 'Python: Select Interpreter', what is the path to the 3.6 installation?

Comment: This `~\anaconda3\envs\py36\python.exe`

Comment: So does `C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\anaconda3\envs\py36\python.exe --version` work?

Comment: Yeah man!!! It did work man. I used this code to install dlib `C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\anaconda3\envs\py36\python.exe -m pip install dlib`